# How to get the uiimage format after converting it into data, getting the images from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, image-formats

I am converting `UIImage` to data using the following code:

```
- (NSString*)getImageTypeWithImage:(UIImage*)img
{
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
NSString *str = [self contentTypeForImageData:imageData];
return str;
}
```

I am using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to convert but it is also        converting the image format to either PNG or JPEG. I am using the below method.

```
- (NSString *)contentTypeForImageData:(NSData *)data 
{
uint8_t c;
[data getBytes:&c length:1];

switch (c) {
    case 0xFF:
        return @"image/jpeg";
    case 0x89:
        return @"image/png";
    case 0x47:
        return @"image/gif";
    case 0x49:
        break;
    case 0x42:
        return @"image/bmp";
    case 0x4D:
        return @"image/tiff";
}
return nil;
}
```

is there a way i Can get the exact image format..please let me know.

Comment: Why don't you use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"image path"];` ?

Comment: @iphonic : I tried the above code, but everytime it is returing 0X01, so it is not going in the Switch case and returning nil value.

Answer (score 0):

I created a test-project using the code below, and this was the result:

```
2014-07-29 09:31:02.904 test[64366:60b] test.jpg = image/jpeg
2014-07-29 09:31:02.907 test[64366:60b] test.png = image/jpeg
2014-07-29 09:31:02.909 test[64366:60b] test.gif = image/jpeg
2014-07-29 09:31:02.909 test[64366:60b] ---
2014-07-29 09:31:02.910 test[64366:60b] test.jpg = image/jpeg
2014-07-29 09:31:02.910 test[64366:60b] test.png = image/png
2014-07-29 09:31:02.910 test[64366:60b] test.gif = image/gif
```

Apparently it's not a good idea to extract the data from the UIImage, since it will always report jpeg. However, extracting the data directly from the file will report the correct content type.

```
- (void)test 
{
    [self logContentTypeForImageFile:@"test.jpg"];
    [self logContentTypeForImageFile:@"test.png"];
    [self logContentTypeForImageFile:@"test.gif"];

    NSLog(@"---");

    [self logContentTypeForResource:@"test" ofType:@"jpg"];
    [self logContentTypeForResource:@"test" ofType:@"png"];
    [self logContentTypeForResource:@"test" ofType:@"gif"];
}

- (void)logContentTypeForResource:(NSString*)resource ofType:(NSString*)type
{
    NSString *filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resource ofType:type];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];

    NSString *result = [self contentTypeForImageData:data];
    NSLog(@"%@.%@ = %@", resource, type, result);
}

- (void)logContentTypeForImageFile:(NSString*)filename
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:filename];
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage);
    NSData *data = (id)CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(provider));

    NSString *result = [self contentTypeForImageData:data];
    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", filename, result);
}

- (NSString *)contentTypeForImageData:(NSData *)data
{
    uint8_t c;
    [data getBytes:&c length:1];

    switch (c) {
        case 0xFF:
            return @"image/jpeg";
        case 0x89:
            return @"image/png";
        case 0x47:
            return @"image/gif";
        case 0x49:
            break;
        case 0x42:
            return @"image/bmp";
        case 0x4D:
            return @"image/tiff";
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: i am fetching the images from Photo Gallery by using UIImagePickerController,i tried with above code, contentTypeForImageData method is returning nil.

Comment: I believe that's because the internal representation of an UIImage has nothing to do with which format it is in, it uses whatever binary format that apple have decided is most efficient. Maybe imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: called by the image picker contains some metadata about the file format.